# Angular 2 subscribe to an attribute of an observable array

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to get one attribute from one object in an observable array of objects. I can get everything except isolating the one object and getting the individual properties.

Here's the service method that's successfully getting the array:

```
getItems(): Observable<IItem[]> {
    return this.get(this.baseUrl + '/items')
      .map((res: Response) => <IItem[]>res.json())
      .do(data => console.log("Items: " + JSON.stringify(data)))
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Trying to get just one object isn't working:

```
 getItem(name: String): Observable<IItem> {
    return this.getItems()
      .map((items: IItem[]) => items.find(item => item.name === name))
      .do(item => console.log("Item: " + item)) 
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Component

```
this._itemsApi.getItem("test")
      .subscribe(
        item => this.testItem = item,
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
```

Template

```
 <widget icon="file" [count]="testItem?.value">
```

JSON

```
["name: test, value: 1","name: test2, value: 0"]
```

Comment: do you have anything in console ? any error ?

Comment: Just undefined in console output

Comment: you mean `Item: undefined`

Comment: this is not array of objects bur array with two strings ["name: test, value: 1","name: test2, value: 0"].array of objects will be [{"name": "test", "value": 1"},{"name": "test2", "value": 0"}]

Comment: Oh man, thx Julia. I knew something was off with that.

Comment: Good. So do u want me to post an answer?

Comment: @JuliaPassynkova, if you want the upvote, sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array of strings, and not array of Objects.
Reformat you API to return back array of objects -> [{"key": "value1"},{"key": "value2"}]. Then you can iterate over these objects and use item.value to get the value of a given item.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. LinQ for TypeScript. this will help you to find one from the array of objects.
https://github.com/kutyel/linq.ts

Follow it's documentation it has everything you need to do.